# How do I make phpmyadmin use a checkbox for boolean?

Tags: phpmyadmin

For boolean columns, I would like to show a checkbox in the data display instead of 0 / 1.

I have changed the column type from TINYINT(1) to BOOLEAN, but no checkbox would appear.

How could I do this?

Thank you!

This is an image of what I would like to show:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a graphical tool for administrators to use for managing a MySQL or MariaDB instance. It's not really meant for your interface to end users. The checkbox you describe is not part of the phpMyAdmin interface and is something you would code in your application for end users.

The checkbox your arrow is pointing at in the screenshot is to select an entire row to perform some operation with, such as deleting, copying, or editing.